# How to implement the Softmax function to each element in a 3d numpy array/matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, computer-vision, softmax

I have defined the softmax function as

```
def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    e_x = np.exp(x) 
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis = 1)
```

I am getting logits as

[image]

Shape of this array is 50 * 3. Now I want to apply softmax function to each element of this array.
When I am using this

```
from scipy.special import expit, logit
y_pred_logits_activated = logit(y_pred_logit)
```

It is giving me the probability value for each class. But when I am doing this

```
y_pred_logits_activated = softmax(y_pred_logit)
```

getting error like this

[image]

How to fix this?

the same question was posted here also with model details
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252515/how-to-get-logit-matrix-from-a-customized-cnn)

---

Further, I want to apply this on logits

[image]

---

Changing the code as

```
def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    e_x = np.exp(x) #
    return np.exp(x)/sum(np.exp(x))
```

solves the issue :)

Comment: FYI, in case you're not aware of it: [`scipy.special.softmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.softmax.html)

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser But I am willing to create a softmax function for distillation, (see edited question). For this I cant use any package.

Comment: SciPy's implementation uses only NumPy (which it looks like is a package that you *can* use), so you could copy the SciPy version from https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/744c75f35b06826c1d61be3e53031d532120cf0a/scipy/special/_logsumexp.py

Comment: Great! I am getting all-zero values. Do you know any method to extract logits from the last layer of any CNN model? I think I am getting the wrong logits :(. BTW thanks @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: Your code wasn’t legal syntax, and didn’t match the code shown in the error message. Don’t re-type code into the question, copy-paste it from your source file. We need to see the exact code you run.